# How to give full control within a folder, but not the folder itself

Tags: windows, permissions, acl, file-permissions, subdirectory

Here's the (very simple) tree I'm working on:

```
C:\
   foo\
       bar\
           ber\
       bat\
           man.txt
       baz\
       ji.txt
```

I want to give **full control** to `bar`, `bat`, `baz`, `ber`, `man.txt` and `ji.txt`, i.e. everything within `foo`. At the same time I want to give `foo` as few permissions as possible, the **bare minimum** to view it's content.

I tried this within the Security tab of `foo`:

- This folder only: Traverse Folder/Execute File & List Folder/Read Data
- Subfolders and files only: Full control
- Disabled inheritance from parent folder (C:\) and enabled propagation

But this doesn't work because then I'm not able to create new files or folders within `foo`.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You've given foo read-only permissions, so of course you can't create new files or folders.  That's what read-only *means*.

Comment: Mmh ok, maybe you're right even if the names of the permissions aren't misleading: foo should be read-only, not its content. My question is still unanswered: how can I have full control within foo, making foo undeletable, unmovable, unrenamable at the same time?

Comment: Answered here: http://superuser.com/a/731102/96662

Comment: Thank you @HarryJohnston, I somehow missed that. That solves my problem.